# iOS TestFlight for other countries?

Tags: testflight, demo, beta-testing

I have an app already release for certain countries, now i want to let someone who are not in the release country to test on it. Since the app is released i can't use TestFlight to invite him to test the current version, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no answer for this, i've simply upload another version only for tester on non release country, i don't think this is the best way but at least it could work.